# pfx keys keep invalidating, why?

Tags: c#, pfx

A simple one, I hope. I create strongly typed assemblies by creating PFX keys. This is fine, I understand what these are for, however. Why is it that on occasion, my project keys invalidate and I get the error(s):

> Error     Importing key file "System.pfx" was canceled.
>
> Error     Cannot import the following key file: System.pfx. The key file
>   may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the
>   certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong
>   Name CSP with the following key container name:
>   VS_KEY_BD649BC5A66E000D.

In know how to fix this, simply re-type the password, but I want to know how to stop this from happening in the first place, what is the cause, and what the best practice is in relation to pfx keys?

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks,

Stu.